# Send data to JSF welcome page

Tags: jsf

I am just getting started using JavaServer Faces and am having a bit of trouble wrapping my mind around how parts of the navigation work.

What I want to do is have my application hit a java method before loading the welcome page in order for that data to be available on the welcome page.  I know how to do this on other pages by creating using the following:

```
<h:commandLink action="#{myController.methodName}" />
```

And then having that method return an outcome that would then go to the page that I want.  However, I am unsure how to do this for the welcome page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the desired code in the constructor of the managed bean class associated with the page.

```
public Bean() {
    // Do your stuff here.
}
```

Alternatively, you can declare a bean method with the [`@PostConstruct`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html) annotation. Such a method will be executed *directly after* construction and initialization/setting of all managed properties.

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    // Do your stuff here.
}
```

This is more useful if the action depends on request parameters and/or another beans.

Comment: How do I associate a managed bean with the page?  Sorry if this is an obvious answer, I'm new to JSF, I'm used to using Servlets and JSP.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Just have `#{bean.property}` somewhere in the page. You want to display some data from it, is it? On `#{bean}` JSF will construct the bean automagically if it's not constructed yet.